# what's the problem with my array push? hook javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, hook, push

```
import * as C from './App.styles';
import * as Stickers from './services/stickers'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { async } from '@firebase/util';
import { Sticker } from './types/Sticker'
import { StickerItem } from './components/StickerItem';

const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [stickers, setStickers] = useState<Sticker[]>([]); 
  const colecao: Sticker[] = [];
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [seesticker, setSeesticker] = useState(false);

  const dropStickerSubmit = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setStickers(await Stickers.getDrop());
    setCount(count+4);
    for(let i=count-4; i<count; i++){
      colecao.push(stickers[i]);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  const defineBoolean = () => {
    setSeesticker(true);
  }
```

colecao.push not works and the array doesn't receive anything. The "stickers" array
it's a hook and he´s work easily. All arrays are Sticker[] type.

Comment: Does TS refuse to compile it, or does the _JavaScript_ that it compiles to not work? Because those are two very different things. There's nothing in your code to suggest that `stickers[i]` is anything, so maybe do some debugging to see what's in `stickers` before you decide `.push` must be broken?

Comment: `const colecao: Sticker[] = [];` isn't a state it's an array object, so every time the App component reloads it get's reset. That's the reason you aren't seeing anything. Trying adding debuggers or console statements to check this